# How to run a scripts before and after connectedDebugAndroidTest runs

Tags: android, ruby, docker, gradle, android-testing

I want to run a bash script from a task (in build.gradle) before the Instrumentation tests starts. That script should run a docker container that contains a ruby bases mock server.

I don't know why I can't get it but this is all I have for now (placed in my build.gradle):

```
task startMock(type:Exec) {
    println("Executing myScript")
    def proc = "cd ../..".execute()
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)

    proc = "../scripts/_mock.sh -a start -p ${projectDir}/../../ -m deps/mock-config".execute()
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    connectedDebugAndroidTest.dependsOn startMock
}
```

The Problem is that the Task runs always, not only on calling `connectedDebugAndroidTest` (or `connectCheck`) ...

I'm confused and appreciate any help :) Maybe someone can give me a hint on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally got it *hoooray* :)

I added the following parts to my build.gradle(app) and now the script is called before and after `connectCheck`has been triggered:

```
task('mockStart', type: Exec){
    doFirst {
        println "MOCK: Start server ..."
    }
    executable "../../scripts/_mock.sh"
    args '-a', 'start', '-p', "${projectDir}/../../", '-m', 'deps/mock-config'
}

task('mockStop', type: Exec){
    doFirst {
        println "MOCK: Stop Server ..."
    }
    executable "../../scripts/_mock.sh"
    args '-a', 'stop', '-p', "${projectDir}/../../", '-m', 'deps/mock-config'
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
   connectedDebugAndroidTest.dependsOn mockStart
   connectedDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy mockStop
}
```

Maybe this will help someone that has some error like I had :)

Good luck & stay tuned!